# Avoid 'infinity' in data aggregates in Google Data Studio or SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, looker-studio

I am building a report in Data Studio, and the data comes from a BigQuery dataset.

The problem is that some values in the table are ***Infinity***, and when Data Studio aggregates in totals or average, the result is always Infinity.

I need to avoid those values in those aggregates. I am trying to do that in Data Studio, or to replace those values by zero in the SQL query.

Is there a way to do either of those things? Is there another way to deal with this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So to anyone reading this. I didn't find a way to deal with infinity in DataStudio or Big Query, so I modified the table for now... That is wrong though, since the true value is Infinity, and zero or null is a misrepresentation of the data. But well, until I know what to do in DataStudio...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "is_inf" function in the where clause and remove any bad data records before aggregation

```
SELECT
   SUM(col2) as aggregated_value
FROM TABLE 1
WHERE IS_INF(col2) = false
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a Case Statement in your aggregation is likely where you'd like to go. If you want to replace this with 0 then the below logic will work.

```sql
SELECT
   SUM(
      CASE
         WHEN col2 = inf THEN 0
         ELSE col2
      END
    ) as aggregated_value
FROM TABLE 1;
```

If you need to do an average, then 0 isn't a good replacement. Instead use NULL as SQL will ignore NULLS in an average:

```sql
SELECT
   AVG(
      CASE
         WHEN col2 = inf THEN NULL
         ELSE col2
      END
    ) as aggregated_value
FROM TABLE 1;
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer. However, the aggregation happens in DataStudio, and the query returns the entire table. Also, BigQuery SQL doesn't recognize inf, do you know how to solve that?